# Can you use a variable to define column name in a Kusto query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

What I'd like to do is roughly this:

```
let column = "environmentName";
exceptions
| summarize count by column
```

The use case is that I use a script to generate various analytics queries, and there's a lot of boilerplate I can avoid by keeping the column dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [columnifexists()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/columnifexists) to achieve that.

For example:

`datatable(value:string)
[ 
   "hello", 
   "world" 
] 
| summarize count() by columnifexists("value", "something else")`